# Duplicate tags [plunker] and [plunkr]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While the site is http://plnkr.co, [plunker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plunker) seems to be the correct name anyway.

Also, it has more questions and a tag-wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[plunkr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plunkr) has been merged into and is a synonym for [plunker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plunker)