# I propose merging the [plunker] tag with the [plunkr] tag

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

How would I/we accomplish this?

See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278227/duplicate-tags-plunker-and-plunkr) [sic].

*This question is not a duplicate because:*

*This post is not a duplicate because the reference you point to is not an actual question. Therefore, there is no way to provide any answer. I don't know if that matters or not because I am new to the meta site. But in my way of seeing things, there needs to be an actual question before someone can answer it. Also, that post has been inactive for 7 months. More evidence that it's impossible to answer a question that is not a question.*

*And lastly, my question above is distinctly requesting a course of action to take in order to resolve the situation.*

Comment: I referenced that post in my question. Please see the explanation in italics.

Comment: The original `synonym-request` has been marked as complete.

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate. The original synonym-request may be a bit lean on details, but that can be remedied. Admittedly, you could only have added details in an answer because you are below 2K. That's one of the few disadvantages of having a real per-site meta since the split. Here on meta, many restrictions from the main-site are relaxed or removed, we even allow some fun: See the titles of the synonym- and burninate-requests, like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298928. Those requests have their own form though...